# How to read file from outside web content directory

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following scriptlet inside a JSP page.

```
  File f = new File("//WEB-INF//music//rock//Evanascence//Fallen//text.txt");
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
  out.println(f.exists());
```

I'm getting a

`FileNotFoundException: \\WEB-INF\music\rock\Evanascence\Fallen\text.txt (The network path was not found)`

Comment: Please note that that file is actually **not** outside the web directory. You perhaps meant outside the **public** web content.

Comment: @BalusC, right. I changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `File` API to reference relative webcontent files. The `File` API operates relative to the current working directory on the local disk file system, which is dependent on how you started the webserver and is in no way controllable from inside the webapplication's code.

In this particular case you should rather use [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29):

```
URL resource = getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/music/rock/Evanascence/Fallen/text.txt");
// ...
```

or

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/music/rock/Evanascence/Fallen/text.txt");
// ...
```

*(note that those double forward slashes are totally unnecessary, I already removed them)*

If it returns `null` then it don't exist. To wrap it in a `Reader`, use [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) wherein you specify the proper character encoding which should be the same as the file is originally saved in:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, needless to say that the code above [belongs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), not in a JSP as you tagged. Inside a JSP, you may find the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)'s [`<c:import>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) tag more useful.

```html
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/music/rock/Evanascence/Fallen/text.txt" />
```

Or if it is possibly non-existing:

```html
<c:catch var="e">
    <c:import url="/WEB-INF/music/rock/Evanascence/Fallen/text.txt" var="text" />
</c:catch>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty e}">
        <pre><c:out value="${text}" /></pre>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <p>An exception occurred when reading file: <pre>${e}</pre></p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks that was a perfect explanation. You are very informative in j2ee. Please suggest resources or techniques that might help me to be as good as u. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Read questions/answers on stackoverflow. Read authoritative books/tutorials.

Comment: Yes, it took me 10 years of continuously learning, reading and practicing.

Comment: Wow, that's a comfort. Thanks again for your timely help.